# Can you scan a document directly, instead of an overview scan first?

Tags: macos, scanning

It honestly really annoys me that every time I have to scan a document it requires me to do an overview scan. Isn't there a way to skip that part if you just want to scan A4 color/B&W using Image Capture on OS X.

I've got a Canon MG5300 printer, although this is irrelevant as an overview scan is required on every printer.

If this can't be accomplished natively, a (great) third party app would be sufficient.

Comment: Could you edit if you are scanning from an iPhone, iPad, networked scanner and/or a Mac connected to a scanner? What software is controlling the scanning? Once this is edited, we can release the temporary hold.

Comment: @bmike Honestly, most of that information is irrelevant, as this is Mac default behaviour. I'm not speaking of my iPhone specifically or a third party application, so I assume we all can say I'm speaking about Mac default applications. However- I will note that specifically.

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer I voted to reopen your question, but for the luck of better understanding, it is always helpful to provide all information, without deciding what is relevant and what not. The readers need to be able to instantly see all the info and not ques. Typically one would list the hardware and the apps (OSX) so to allow for better responses. Best is if you could list what have you tried as well.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Can't deny that. Hopefully this, above, is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to configure the scanner so that pressing the button on the console automatically sends the image data to a folder on your computer, without going through **Image Capture**.

Another option, since you asked about third-party apps, is [Vue Scan](http://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/canon_mg5300.html) which is well-supported, and can scan without first doing a preview.

(edit to add) yet another third-party app would be [Paperless](https://marinersoftware.com/products/paperless/), which while technically is more of an archiving solution, it also will scan directly to its library without a preview.